# Prevent TFS Checkout without locking by user

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have directories in TFS (server is 2010, users are using VS 2012 and 2013), which I want to prevent anyone from working in. I still want them to be there, so users can read the files and view history, but I don't want to let them check anything out or in.

The reason is that we have a bunch of outdated branches which people have created all willy-nilly with terrible names over the years, and we're hoping to not have to move/reorganize them all right now - but I don't want anyone new to accidentally work on one of the old branches without realizing it.

I can lock the directories, but then they show up indefinitely in my on personal changes as locked - I don't want this junking up my workspace, and if I ever leave, I'm sure my locks will be removed anyway.

Is there any "disable" command or anything else I can do to stop checkouts/checkins on directories?

Comment: TFS has a good permissions system. Just make them read-only for everyone but yourself and admins.

Comment: Thanks - wasn't thinking from a permission perspective, but that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you right click on the branch you should get security options. in TFS 2013 its Advanced > Security (sorry not got 2010 instance in front of me)

you can then set permissions on the branch, set read for your normal users and disable Check in / check out for them

Comment: Didn't even think about that - I forgot to mention that the users are all admins too (yeah I know, bad idea). I figured you couldn't take away admin rights, but I just tried removing the rights from everyone, including admins, and it works fine - I can't check files out myself, without going back in and giving myself permission (which is good enough for me). Thanks.